# Changing text on TextView elements on threads each x seconds

Tags: android, textview

I want to make a thread which is executed every 1 second, the function which is executed executed periodically must modify a TextView object which corresponds to a xml element for the user interface. I show you now the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

  //Object which will be modified by the thread
  public TextView distance;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    distance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);

    //Declaring 1-second periodic thread
    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(
      new Runable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
          System.out.println("works before"); //Just for debugging
          Random random = new Random();
          distance.setText("" + random.nextInt(100));
          System.out.println("works afterwards"); //Just for debugging
        }
      }
    , 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

But the problem is that when I run this code, the line which set the text on the TextView object is only executed once, the result on the debugging log on Eclipse seems like this:

```
System.out: works before
System.out: works afterwards
System.out: works before
```

And here it remains blocked, but in the app there is also a button and even the thread is blocked, I can interact and execute the functions which this button launchs. To make sure that the problem was the line when changing the value of the TextView, commented on code this line:

```
...
        public void run(){
          System.out.println("works before"); //Just for debugging
          Random random = new Random();
          //distance.setText("" + random.nextInt(100));
          System.out.println("works afterwards"); //Just for debugging
        }
...
```

And the results on the debugging log are:

```
System.out: works before
System.out: works afterwards
System.out: works before
System.out: works afterwards
System.out: works before
System.out: works afterwards
```

And it never finishes (it repeats each second), my knowledge about android structure is not so advanced, so if someone could give me a tip about where is the mistake, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the UI from outside the UI thread. Anyway, It's easier to just use a handler for this.

```
    final Handler mUIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mUIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        Random random = new Random();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            distance.setText("" + random.nextInt(100));
            mUIHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);                    
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the code you wrote, and the problem dissapeared, thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand why in the first situation the application does not crash. In the first case you need to run the `setText` on the UI thread but the timer runs in a different thread. This issue is easily fixable.. just use an `Handler` to post on the UI Thread. On the other hand, you could take in consideration the possibility to use an Handler and its `postDelayed` method. The main vantage is that it runs on the UI thread and for not heavy computation is ok to use it

Comment: I used the solution with Handler and postDelayed method, and it worked, thanks! :)